# How to display results from form search, connected to database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The code I'm going to present you is not working. No results are displaying for the IF condition. But for Else are. When I call $service_id alone with echo, it gives me the ID that I searched for but when used in the WHERE close: service_id = '$service_id' nothing is displayed.

```
<form method="GET" name="pesquisa" id="inserrifo" action="/services.php">
    <input class="procurasalgo" id='pesqSign' name="keyword" value="<?php echo $keyword;?>" placeholder="Inserir palavra"/><label for="pesqSign" id="pesqSigne"><img class="lupapesquisa" src="/img/search-26.png" /></label>
    <select name="services">
        <option disabled selected value=''>Serviços</option>
        <?php
            $res = $DAL->mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM services");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['serv_id']."'>".$row['serv_name']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name='distritos'>
        <option disabled selected value=''>Portugal</option>
        <?php
            $res = $DAL->mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM distritos");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                echo "<option value='".$row['d_id']."'>".$row['d_nome']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <button>Procurar</button>
</form>
```

" placeholder="Inserir palavra"/>
    
        Serviços
        mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM services");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                echo "".$row['serv_name']."";
            }
        ?>
    
    
        Portugal
        mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM distritos");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                echo "".$row['d_nome']."";
            }
        ?>
    
    Procurar

```
<?php   

    $service_id = $_GET['services'];
    $district_id = $_GET['distritos'];
    $keywords = $_GET['keyword'];


    if ($service_id != '' || $district_id != '' || $keywords != '') {

    $result = $DAL->mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users, services, distritos, users_services WHERE u_id = user_id && service_id = '$service_id' && distrito_id = '$district_id' ");

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $img_user = $row['u_foto'];


        echo "<div class='Services'><img src='http://mufip.pt/images/userimages/avatars/".$img_user."' /><br /><h5>".$row['u_name']."<h5><h6>".substr($row['u_descricao'],0, 140)."</h6></div>";

        } //while

    } //if

    else {

    $result = $DAL->mysqlQuery("SELECT * FROM users, services, distritos, users_services WHERE u_id = user_id && service_id = serv_id && distrito_id = d_id ORDER BY RAND()");

    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    echo $num." resultados<br />";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $img_user = $row['u_foto'];

    echo "<div class='Services'><img src='http://mufip.pt/images/userimages/avatars/".$img_user."' /><br /><h5>".$row['u_name']."<h5><h6>".substr($row['u_descricao'],0, 140)."</h6></div>";

        } //while

    } //else

    ?>
```

Comment: The where condition of your query is not working. Am I right? @Domingos Pereira

Comment: You're right.
The where condition inside the IF is not working. But the where condition inside the ELSE is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($service_id != '' || $district_id != '' || $keywords != '') {
```

line is checking presence of any fields between three. In other words this logical check will give you TRUE when $service_id or $district_id or $keywords is not empty. 
Suppose, user entered values for only "keywords" and in this page, you will get value of only $keywords and $service_id and $district_id will be empty.

Since one of them (here $keywords) is not empty, IF statement will return true and program control will move inside it.

However , in the SQL  query you are using AND condition and that requires valid or non-empty value in service_id & distrito_id columns. Since one of them might remain empty, this query will produce no result.

To debug the situation, select value from one of the drop-down only and use echo statement to print the query inside IF block.

Comment: Hi. I understand what you say, But in that case, the code should work when all 3 values all selected in search form. It should. But it still gives me 0 input in search display :/

Comment: another flaw with you code is that tables are not joined properly inside IF block. Did you tried to "echo" the SQL & run directly in MySql ?

Answer (score 0):

I had help from a friend :)

```
public function returnSelectService($nomeSelect,$idSelect,$nomeCampo,$stringSQL,$selected = null)
{       
    $list = "<select class=\"selectServicesList\" id=\"$idSelect\" name=\"$nomeSelect\">";
    $list .="<option value=\"\">Serviços</option>";
    $res = $this->mysqlQuery($stringSQL);
    $select = "";


    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
    {
        if($selected != null && $selected == $linha->serv_id)
            $select = 'selected="selected"';            
        $list .="<option $select  value=\"$linha->serv_id\">".$linha->$nomeCampo."</option>";
        $select = "";
    }
    $list .= "</select>";
    return  $list;
}



public function returnSelectDistrict($nomeSelect,$idSelect,$nomeCampo,$stringSQL,$selected = null)
{       
    $list = "<select class=\"selectServicesList\" id=\"$idSelect\" name=\"$nomeSelect\">";
    $list .="<option value=\"\">Portugal</option>";
    $res = $this->mysqlQuery($stringSQL);
    $select = "";


    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_object($res)) 
    {
        if($selected != null && $selected == $linha->d_id)
            $select = 'selected="selected"';            
        $list .="<option $select  value=\"$linha->d_nome\">".$linha->$nomeCampo."</option>";
        $select = "";
    }
    $list .= "</select>";
    return  $list;
}




    <form method="GET" name="pesquisa" id="inserrifo" action="/services.php">
            <br />
            <?php
            echo $DAL->returnSelectService('services','services','serv_name',"SELECT * FROM services ",$service_id);
            ?>          
            <?php
            echo $DAL->returnSelectDistrict('distritos','distritos','d_nome',"SELECT * FROM distritos ",$d_id); 
            ?>  
            <button class="btn btn-default">Procurar</button>
        </form>



    <?php   


$stringSQL ="SELECT * FROM users, services, distritos, users_services WHERE u_id = user_id AND service_id = serv_id AND distrito_id = d_id ";
if($service_id != "")
    $stringSQL .=" AND serv_id = '{$service_id}'  ";
if($district_id != "")
    $stringSQL .="AND d_id = '{$district_id}' ";
$stringSQL .="ORDER BY RAND()";


        $result = $DAL->mysqlQuery($stringSQL);

        $num = mysql_numrows($result);

            echo $num." resultados<br />";      

            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $img_user = $row['u_foto'];

            echo "<div class='services'>
            <div class='servicesBox'>
            <img src='http://mufip.pt/images/userimages/avatars/".$img_user."' />
            <h4>".$row['u_name']."</h4><br />
            <h5>".$row['serv_name'].", ".$row['d_nome']."</h5><br />
            <p>".substr($row['u_descricao'],0, 200)." ...</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div style='clear: both; background-color: white; height: 15px'>
            </div>";

                }

            ?>
```